# Block RF in DC line, SMA

Tags: rf, filter, low-pass

I have a coaxial line delivering DC to a bunch of RF amplifiers. The amplifiers are connected all in parallel in a chain in this way:

[image]

This is a chain of SMA cables and tees going into each amp. As I am experiencing some oscillations, especially in the units that are in the end of this chain, I want to add some RF blocking filter in this line. Do products for this purpose exist, ready to buy plug and play? What is their name? Otherwise, how would this be implemented? I can think of LC filters, but would this need some special L and or C to dissipate the high frequency (in the core of the coil or the dielectric of the capacitor)?

I know the specific solution can depend highly on my particular problem, but I am just looking for general orientation.

Comment: Why do you think the RF blocking filters will help the oscillations?

Comment: I don't know it, but why not to try? If there exists such filters, it is a trivial test.

Comment: Yes, these products exist. They might be described as a low-pass filter, or a choke. Look in the same place you got your SMA cables and tees - they might also sell filters.

Comment: @user171780 - Not trying to be snitty here, but that is not good engineering practice.  That's more like a hack - try something, anything, and see if it works.

Comment: Is it one amplifier oscillating, or two as a pair?  If individual amplifiers are oscillating, are they doing so at the same frequency?  You may have an input/output isolation problem, or leakage, not related to the DC power path.

Comment: SMA coax cables are typically used for RF or RF and DC, not just DC. There is a  component called a "bias tee" which can be used to feed DC and terminate RF. If you look at the connections, they are sort of backwards from what you are looking for but could be hacked for what you want. It may not fix your oscillation, as others have noted.

Answer (score 0):

Unintended oscillations in linear amplifiers are due to some unknown amount of positive feedback.  This could be crosstalk or conducted or load regulated.   Without design details, it's hard to generalize how to decouple RF from DC supply, but there must be some defined specs.

It is common in RF to use RC or RLC filters depending on the attenuation required for load-regulated noise and source impedance versus frequency on DC.  You need some isolation in impedance ratios between RF and DC, but there is no generalized solution.